# How to find Find max right using stack?

Tags: algorithm, stack

I was solving the question where we need to find rightSpecialValue for each A[i] in given array A. RightSpecialValue is defined below.

`RightSpecialValue: For an index i, it is defined as the index j such that A[j]>A[i] and (j>i). If multiple A[j]'s are present in multiple positions, the RightSpecialValue is the minimum value of j. Here RightSpecialValue is the index j and not A[j].`

It could be easily solved using by using stack in O(n) but what if it is changed to "If multiple A[j]'s are present in multiple positions, the RightSpecialValue is the **maximum** value of j. Here RightSpecialValue is the index j and not A[j]."

is there any better solution than O(n^2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any better solution than O(n^2)?

There is at least a O(log) solution for it:

- Maintain a vector (with direct indexing, to which only elements are pushed, never popped): it will gradually get populated with indices for which it is true that all values *after* an included index are *less* than the value at that index.
- Iterate the array from right to left, and for each visited index `i` do:

  - Perform a binary search in the vector with the current value `a[i]`, so that we find the greatest `j` on the vector for which `a[j] > a[i]`, if any. Register this `j` (or a default -1) for this index `i` as part of the solution.
  - If `a[i]` is greater than the value at the index that is on the top of the vector, then push `i` on the vector.

The time complexity of this algorithm is O(log1 + log2 + log3 + ... + log) = O(log).

Comment: This is the same algorithm as the one that was already there as answer and you can't binary search a stack because you can only look at the top element. You say it is basically a vector but still use the word stack.

Comment: @maraca, both answers were posted at about the same time. I have renamed stack with vector. Thanks.

Comment: I see, the answer is good, but what I think is not fair is that the other answer didn't get any upvotes except mine even though it is the same algorithm, not that it really matters, but I noticed a tendency of some people to upvote the answer of the one with the most points.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could solve this new problem in O(nlogn) by creating a candidates list which is initially empty and holds indexes. Now you go backwards and for each index i you find the smallest a[j] > a[i] by bisection where j are the indexes in the candidates list (the candidates list is sorted ascending). If you didn't find such an index add i to the candidates (and set i to -1 or null or whatever in result). If you found an index j in candidates set result[i] = j.